# How do you say “My car is not big. But, it’s not small either”?

Tags: english-to-japanese, phrase-requests, particle-も

I am having trouble finding out if I’m correct on this.

The statement I would like to translate is,

`My car is not big, but it’s not small either`.

With the knowledge I have, it would be `わたしのくるまはおおきくないです。でも、ちいさくないです。`

But then the second statement doesn’t really provide a “too.” If I repeat the topic, as such:

```
わたしのくるまも~
```

…isn’t that “against the rule” or it sounds unnatural?

I am a total beginner in Japanese. But even then, I can’t seem to find the right answer to this.

I hope you can help me. Arigato gouzamaisu! ^_^

Answer (score 5):

も applies to the thing it is attached to. 私｛わたし｝の車｛くるま｝も小｛ちい｝さくないです。 is 'My car is not small, either' maybe in comparison to another car.

For sentences like this, you want to use は and も in tandem, on the adjective. 私｛わたし｝の車｛くるま｝は大｛おお｝きく**は**ないですが、小｛ちい｝さく**も**ないです。 This は acts is a contrastive は, I believe, acting almost like emphasis - 'My car is not *big*, but it's not small, *either*.'

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want a neutral, non-contrastive statement, you could simply use 2 もs.  私の車は大きくも、小さくもない.